# How to reset password of other users in firebase authentication?

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication, admin, forgot-password

I am creating a simple web portal using firebase cloud authentication. One user is an admin who will create other normal users and handover the credentials to normal user.

```
var newUser = firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newEmail, newPassword);
```

Now I want that admin should have option to reset password for any normal user.

How can I achieve this? Can anyone please share any idea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by calling `updateUser()` in the Admin SDK. The sample from [this documentation page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user):

```
admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {
  email: "modifiedUser@example.com",
  emailVerified: true,
  password: "newPassword",
  displayName: "Jane Doe",
  photoURL: "http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png",
  disabled: true
})
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log("Successfully updated user", userRecord.toJSON());
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error updating user:", error);
  });
```

This functionality is only available in the Node.js version of the Admin SDK at the moment.

Comment: curious if there is a backend shell in the console to run some admin sdk commands? kind of like the shell for cloud sql.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not. A local node script is the fastest I found.